# Why i get the memory address of this element?

Tags: c

test how "*++p" should be in C language,i debug my code in codeblocks,but it got that value:"*++p=6356748";according to the book C primer plus,it should be 20.why i get this?
th is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int arr[]={10,20};
    int *p=arr;
    printf("*P=%d\n",*p);
    printf("*p++=%d\n",*p++);
    printf("++*p=%d\n",++*p);
    printf("*++p=%d\n",*++p);
}
```

and the debug result:

```
*P=10
*p++=10
++*p=21
*++p=6356748
```

Comment: The `++` operator has higher precedence than `*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first printf prints the first element of arr, and leaves the pointer p alone.  The second printf prints the first element again, and then increments the pointer p after printing, so now p points to the second element of arr.  The third printf gets the second element of p, and then increments it, but leaves p unchanged.  The final printf, increments p, so it is now pointing past the end of arr, and then tries to print out the contents of that address.  There's no way of knowing what will be there.

Comment: thanks!but i still don't know why the last printf will print the memory address, it shouldn't be the value of that memory address?

Comment: The last print is **not** printing the memory address but the contents at that address. Like bruceg said, this is out of bounds and there is no way of knowing which value it will be there. In fact, your program might end with a segfault because accessing memory out of bounds is undefined behaviour